# filtering out docs that have a word from a stop list

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search query for some such as `"match":{"product name":"glasses car"}` so that I am looking for glasses or cars (or both).

But I want to exclude the docs that have `google glass` or `google car` in them. so how would I filter them out?

I could use a bool query and use must_not for `google`, but then I will lose the scoring and get a constant score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `filtered query` with a `filter` to exclude words like `google` and keep your main search as the `query`.

The `filter` does not affect scoring, only the `query` part of the filtered query does.

You can find a small example on the [Filtered Query page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/) in the ElasticSearch documentation.